# Is there a name for this kind of proof?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

I, unfortunately, can't recall a specific proof that performs this kind of reasoning, but I remember seeing a few vague examples in my Real Analysis class a while back. It may simply be called a Proof by Contradiction, but I wonder if there is a stronger term.

Basically when trying to prove a statement true, the line of reasoning goes:

"Here's this crazy mathematical object that I came up with. It has these very obscure properties. Assume that the statement we want to prove true is false. If the statement is false, then that would violate at least one of the obscure properties of my crazy object. Therefore, the statement must be true."

Thanks for reading! I appreciate any insight :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: cf. [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)

Answer (score 1):

The craziness of the object and obscurity of its properties aren't mathematical facts, they're just judgments people happen to make *(and may well 'un-make' in the future!)*. The proof itself is just a proof by contradiction.

Now that said, there is a *practical* issue here, namely that proofs of any type which "blackbox" obscure facts may have hard-to-detect errors (the facts in question may be misstated or applied incorrectly in ways that one not familiar with them might not notice). But that's an issue of practice; assuming the proof is actually correct, it's not relevant.

Moreover, in any area of mathematics it's very important to be familiar with a wide range of odd objects which function as useful counterexamples. So while they may appear strange to you at the moment, there's a good chance you'll become quite familiar with them over time.

Comment: There's an step in the proof outlined above that it's important not to overlook.  You need to prove that the crazy mathematical object with obscure properties actually exists.

Comment: @RobertShore Indeed - nonexistence is sadly a *common* property of crazy objects. ([Not always disqualifying](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182006/what-is-the-most-useful-non-existing-object-of-your-field), though! :P)